# How to wait when another process in accessing a file?

Tags: perl

I use PopId() and PushId() to have many users share 10 login ids to a system. Sometime I got this error:

> Could not open '\ccreqpwebp01\ccstg\Informatica\APIUSR.txt' -
>   Permission denied at \ccreqpwebp01\ccstg\Informatica/bccpbmod.pm line
>   1206.

line 1206 is to open the file to write. PopId() pops the first id from the APIUSR.txt, delete APIUSR.txt and then recreate the APIUSR.txt with the rest of ids.

Can anyone help me to get it right?

`test_id.pl`:

```
$api_usr_file = "APIUSR.txt";
$id = PopId();
print "pop id=$id\n";
PushId($id);

sub PopId {
   $path_to_file = $api_usr_file;
   #$path_to_file = "\\\\ccreqpwebd01\\ccstg\\Unix\\APIUSR.txt";
   # Read file into the array
   open (my $fh, '<', $path_to_file) or die "Could not open '$path_to_file'     - $!";
   chomp(my @lines = <$fh>);
   close $fh;
   #print "Before Pop: @lines\n";
   # Pop the first id
   my $uid = "";
   while ($uid eq "") {
      $uid = shift(@lines);
   }
   print "Pop id:$uid\n";
   #print "After Pop:@lines\n";

   # Write the rest of ids back to the file
   unlink $path_to_file or die "Could not delete '$path_to_file' - $!";
   open (my $fd, ">>$path_to_file") or die "Could not open '$path_to_file' -     $!";
   sleep 3;
   foreach (@lines) {
      print $fd $_;
      print $fd "\n";
   }
   close $fd;
   return $uid;
}

sub PushId {
   $path_to_file = $api_usr_file;
   #$path_to_file = "\\\\ccreqpwebd01\\ccstg\\Unix\\APIUSR.txt";
   my ($uid) = @_;
   # Read file into the array
   open (my $fh, '<', $path_to_file) or die "Could not open '$path_to_file'     - $!";
   chomp(my @lines = <$fh>);
   close $fh;
   #print "Before Push:@lines\n";

   # unshift(@lines,$uid);
   push (@lines,$uid);
   #print "After push:@lines\n";
   # Write to the file
   unlink $path_to_file or die "Could not delete '$path_to_file' - $!";
   open(my $fd, ">>$path_to_file") or die "Could not open '$path_to_file' -     $!";
   sleep 3;
   foreach (@lines) {
      print $fd $_;
      print $fd "\n";
   }
   close $fd;
}
```

`APIUSR.txt`:

```
APIUSR06
APIUSR07
APIUSR08
APIUSR09
APIUSR01
APIUSR02
APIUSR00
APIUSR03
APIUSR04
APIUSR05
```

Comment: Getting it right would involve using proper synchronization. At the very least, check out [`flock`](https://metacpan.org/pod/perlfunc#flock-FILEHANDLE-OPERATION).

Comment: Thanks, I will try this: http://www.perlmonks.org/?node_id=7058. Overall, is there a better way to achieve this: many users to share a few login ids.

Comment: Likely explanations: 1) File permissions prevent you from writing to the file. 2) Someone else has the file open, and they opened it in a way that prevents others from writing to it. 3) The file has been deleted, but someone still has an open handle to it.

Comment: Your subs are overly complex.  If you use the [Tie::File module](http://search.cpan.org/~toddr/Tie-File-1.00/lib/Tie/File.pm), you can reduce that down to 3 lines of code.  I don't see the connection between your code and your need for "***many users to share a few login ids***".

Comment: @RonBergin, this is great. Is this thread safe? Means when multiple processes trying to access the same file. My above program is having an issue: the APIUSR.txt totally missing.